# How to clear textbox after unchecking checkbox without textbox disappearing (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, textbox

I am new to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a form which has an element that uses geolocation to get the current location of a user when user checks a checkbox, and it inputs the coordinates inside a textbox that I've set up. This works fine, but when I uncheck the checkbox, the coordinates disappear along with the textbox.

How do I clear just the coordinates without making the textbox disappear as well?

Below is my code:

```js
function getLocation(myCheck) {

  var x = document.getElementById("place");

  if (myCheck.checked) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation disabled or unavailable.";
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<h4> Coordinates: <label id="place"><input type="text"></label><label>Use current location? <input id="myCheck" onclick="getLocation(this)" type="checkbox"></label>
</h4>
```

Comment: set one id to the input text and later  document.getElementById('elementid').value = "";

Answer (score 2):

To empty an input you need to set the value instead of `innerHTML`. Also note you can avoid creating an input inside the `label` tag by just using the `id` & `for` attribute

```js
function getLocation(myCheck) {

  var x = document.getElementById("place");

  if (myCheck.checked) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.value = "Geolocation disabled or unavailable.";
    }
  } else {
    x.value = "";
  }
}


function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

```html
<h4> Coordinates: <label for="place">
<input id ="place" type="text"></label>
  <label for="myCheck">Use current location?
<input id="myCheck" onclick="getLocation(this)" type="checkbox">
</label>
</h4>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I moved the definition of var x to before the getLocation() function definition. So thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try?

```
document.getElementById('myCheck').value = "";
```

Comment: This kinda worked but nothing is appearing in the textbox now.